# Trouble with nested IF in cmd batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The batch file below intends to find all files that don't match the set pattern and delete them. However, it won't execute at all. Looks like there is syntax issue in the IF statement that I couldn't find.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET SHARE_FOLDER=\\blyfs01\teams$\Hadoop\Workday\
SET WKDAY_FNAME=WKDY_HADOOP_PTODATA
FOR %%F in ("%SHARE_FOLDER%*.*") DO ( SET FNAME=%%~nxF & IF !FNAME:~0,28!==!WKDAY_FNAME!_%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2% ( @ECHO DO @DEL %%F) )
```

Comment: You don't need arcane batch workarounds like delayed variable expansion or string date parsing if you use PowerShell.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, I have to use batch for this case. Do you happen to know anything with the syntax of nested IF statement?

Comment: `for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b "%sharefolder%*.*"') do ...` but also be aware of hidden spaces, its better `set "wkday_fname=wk..."` and use quotes in `if` string comparisions as `if "xxx" == "%myvar%"` to avoid hidden trailing / leading spaces. also ensure what date format has your system!

Comment: @elzooilogico It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: "I have to use batch for this case" - why?

Comment: There are some other components I already did research how to use batch. Switching to powershell would need to re-do my research.

Comment: Switching to PowerShell will be well worth the investment.

Answer (score 0):

elzooilogico got it right. It literally is the quote that made it work!

`FOR %%F in ("%SHARE_FOLDER%*.*") DO ( SET FNAME=%%~nxF & IF "!FNAME:~0,28!" NEQ "!WKDAY_FNAME!_%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%" (@ECHO @DEL %%F) )`

Comment: `set "fname=%%~nxF"` as `set fname="%%~nxF"` is not what you expect. also you are enclosing in quotes and removing them `~` ;-)